# Create URL shortcut in Android home screen programmatically

Tags: android, url, shortcut

Does anyone have example code for creating URL shortcut on the android device home screen ?

I want my app to create some shortcuts to URL.

Answer (score -2):

What do you want to do if the home screen is already full?
I think there are several good reasons why the user should be involved.

This link shows how a user can do it manually:
 http://androidforums.com/htc-desire/197568-internet-shortcuts.html

And it contains another link to an app that lets you make custom icons etc.
 http://www.folderorganizer.net/how-to/change-label-icon/

If you make a widget for your app, you can programmatically change URL shortcuts that appear in your widget ;-)

Comment: you didn't answer the original question.